# this.schedulerActionCtor is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, redux-observable

[image] Facing an error
-> `this.schedulerActionCtor is not a constructor`

I need help with this error.

I get it from `epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic)` .

Here is the source code - https://github.com/flipflopapp/react-redux-epics-typescript-2021-boilerplate (can anyone help out)

This line is in file - https://github.com/flipflopapp/react-redux-epics-typescript-2021-boilerplate/blob/main/src/boot/configureStore.ts

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using "redux-observable" or another library that has "rxjs" as a dependency then you need to update it also.

Comment: Instead of simply providing the answer directly, try writing a detailed comment that explains the solution, as long as the explanation is not too lengthy. @Oleksandr Romanowskyi .

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem mentioned above due to version compatability of `redux-observable@2.0.0` with `rxjs@7.5.5`

**Solution:**

redux-observable@2.0.0 require peer dependencies of rxjs@6.x.x and redux@4.x.x.

but i have rxjs@7.x.x. In official web site they mentioned

Note: current stable version redux-observable doesn't work with rxjs@7.x.x, it works with rxjs@6.x.x. If you still want to use rxjs@7.x.x, upgrade to redux-observable@2.0.0-rc.2.